# Recurring ISSUE - After enabling Kerberos, Kerberos service is missing from list of Ambari services in UI

Tags: kerberos, hadoop2, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I'm currently having this recurring issue:
whenever I try to make changes in Ranger or Kerberos, the Kerberos service and clients go missing from Ambari services in UI - even when Kerberos is enabled.

I found earlier that my `kerberos-env` and `krb5-conf` files were missing in my Ambari database, hence with the below command I was able to push my files to my Ambari DB. (The version_tag was version1000)

```
curl -H "X-Requested-By:ambari" -u admin:admin -i -X PUT -d @./payload.json http://<Ambari-Server>:8080/api/vi/clusters/<Cluster-Name>;
```

But after 1 month, I'm having the same issues. So, when I try repeating the above step, I get the below error stating that `version1000` exists.
Can I change the `version_tag` to `version1001` or something.
Will that be able to resolve the below error?
And is there a permanent fix?

```
{
  "status" : 500,
  "message" : "org.apache.ambari.server.controller.spi.SystemException: An internal system exception occurred: Configuration with tag 'version1000' exists for 'kerberos-env'"
}
```

Any help to fix this issue is greatly appreciated.
My software versions are

- HDP    - 2.6.3 and
- Ambari - 2.5.2